# ¿Existe alguna clasificación de palabras para determinar si son positivas o negativas?

Tags: recursos, connotaciones

Investigando un poco sobre el análisis automático de textos, me interesó mucho esta parte de "análisis sentimental" (sentimental analysis / opinion mining). Me gustaría profundizar algo más en el tema (en inglés hay mucho contenido, pero no tanto en español) y tengo algunas dudas que tal vez alguien podría aclararme.

1. ¿Alguien conoce alguna clasificación abierta/libre de palabras según su positividad o negatividad en español? En inglés encontré [AFINN](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010).
2. Como curiosidad, ¿existe alguna propiedad de las palabras en la lengua española que determine estrictamente si una palabra es negativa o positiva? Sé que serían muy pocas, ya que dependiendo de la frase, una palabra de connotación negativa puede tener una connotación positiva; pero por ejemplo: "maldad", "infierno", "aterrador" podrían considerarse palabras estrictamente negativas. Sé que es un tema bastante subjetivo, pero me gustaría saber vuestras opiniones.

Comment: En respuesta a tu curiosidad, creo que se aproxima los *adjetivos calificativos positivos* y los *adjetivos calificativos negativos*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los adjetivos, que informan de una cualidad del sustantivo, tienen **grados**:

- Positivo: muestra una cualidad sin cuantificarla ni compararla
- Comparativo: establece una relación (Superioridad, igualdad, inferioridad)
- Superlativo: intensifica al máximo la cualidad expresada

Ni sustantivos ni adjetivos poseen en nuestra lengua cualidad alguna que denote su *polaridad* (carga afectiva).

Hasta donde yo sé, no hay tal clasificación como la que necesitas para los sustantivos, y menos "*oficial*" (que involucre a la RAE).

Creo que si estás diseñando un programa que haga un *análisis sentimental* quizá tendrás que construir tu propia base de conocimiento y asignar tú mismo pesos a las palabras (como creo que have AFINN). Yo no he sido capaz de encontrar un sistema que categorize a las palabras, pero sí he encontrado programas que hacen este análisis sentimental (minería de datos para Twitter, procesamiento de lenguaje natural, etc.). Estos programas o estudios construyen su sistema de clasificación ellos mismos (cogen por ejemplo el diccionario de Microsoft Word y asignan valencias ellos mismos, como en este [ejemplo de Sentiex](http://tecnolengua.uma.es/doc2/sepln2010_sentitexta.pdf)).

Casi todos los programas de procesamiento de lenguaje natural, tesis sobre el tema, etc. que he podido encontrar por la red suelen seguir este enfoque. [Esta tesis](http://nlp.uned.es/~jcalbornoz/papers/PhD_Thesis_2011.pdf) cita un léxico (*SentiSense*) que ellos mismos desarrollaron previamente. Quizá puedas contactar con alguno de los departamentos o estudiantes realizando estos programas o estudios y conseguir que te dejen usas sus sistemas de clasificación. Dado que son estudiantes de investigación, quizá no sea difícil conseguir que te dejen hacer uso de ellas, mientras les cites apropiadamente en cualquier cosas que tú realices como los desarrolladores de tales trabajos.

Comment: De mucha ayuda. Mil gracias :)